# Robocopy to Linux Samba server over unreliable VPN resulted in corrupt files yet Robocopy said all files copied/matched

Tags: linux, windows, samba, robocopy

I ran into an interesting problem where I ran robocopy to copy hundreds of GB of files to a remote location for a test lab, the vpn dropped several times, copies retried - due to bandwidth limitations it was stopped, etc. All things that can explain why this happened.

After getting to the point robocopy said the directories matched with no errors we had problems with several of the files.

Comment: Maybe you should submit a trouble report to Robocopy and see what they have to say.  Perhaps there's a validation option that you could have checked or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To fix I ran rsync to Linux with -c (checksum compare of files instead of other algorithms). This resulted in thousands of files mismatching and being updated.

I couldn't find a windows only way to fix this easier given the bandwidth restrictions.

```
rsync --inplace --cza --progress //server/share/dir/* rsync://server/share/dir/
```